# VB.NET Determine Time Difference Between Two Dates and Times

Tags: vb.net

I have been searching for this answer for days now and cannot find a simple solution. I have a simple form with two buttons "JOB START" & "JOB FINISH". The button text equals the date/time "Now" once pressed. All I want to do is have a label show the total time once "JOB FINISHED" is pressed in the format hh:mm:ss

```
Me.btnStart.Text = 10/1/2014 05:30:00
Me.btnStop.Text = 10/1/2014 06:45:00

' Result should read:
Me.Label1.Text = 01:15:00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether you have `Dates` or only `Strings`. If the latter you first have to parse the string to date by using `Date.Parse(btnStart.Text)` or `Date.TryParse(btnStart.Text, dateVariable)`.

But once you have both dates you can calculate the duration from `dt1 - dt2` which returns a `TimeSpan` object, [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the desired string:

```
Dim stopDate As Date
Dim stopIsDate As Boolean = Date.TryParse(btnStop.Text, stopDate)
Dim startDate As Date
Dim startIsDate As Boolean = Date.TryParse(btnStart.Text, startDate)
If stopIsDate AndAlso startIsDate Then
    Dim diff As TimeSpan = stopDate - startDate
    Me.Label1.Text = diff.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
End If
```

Another way is to create a `DateTime` where the date is ignored, then you can use all `Date` methods like [`ToLongTimeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongtimestring(v=vs.110).aspx). It's also easier to provide the correct formats:

```
Dim time As Date = Date.Today.Add(diff) ' Add takes a TimeSpan
Me.Label1.Text = time.ToLongTimeString() 
' or '
Me.Label1.Text = time.ToString("T")
' or '
Me.Label1.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss") ' upper-case HH is 24h clock '
```

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank You Tim Schmelter... this works great! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Public Class FMain

```
Dim startTime As DateTime
Dim endTime As DateTime
Dim duration As TimeSpan

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      startTime = DateTime.Now
    A1.Text = startTime.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss") ' A1 is a text box
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    endTime = DateTime.Now
    A2.Text = endTime.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    duration = endTime - startTime
    A3.Text = duration.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub
```

end class

Comment: An explanation would be nice.